# OnChange method does not work when trying to get text from input - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a chat and the problem I am having has to do with creating a new chat. When clicking on the button to create a new chat, a popup appears with the chat name field to fill in. However, when I click on "Create Now" I can't get the input text.
I've tried adding value = {nameChat} but this way I can't write to the input. Nothing appears. I also tested defaultValue = {nameChat} but it doesn't work either.
If anyone could help me, I would appreciate it.

[Popup to create new chat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDH53.png)

```
import { confirmAlert } from 'react-confirm-alert'; // Import
import 'react-confirm-alert/src/react-confirm-alert.css' // Import css
import { useState } from 'react'

const HeaderChats = ({ onAddNewChat }) => {

var [chatName, setChatName] = useState(''); 

const onSubmit = (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    if (!chatName) {
        alert('Please write the name of the chat!')
        console.log("Nome -> " + chatName)
        return
    }

    console.log(chatName)
    onAddNewChat(chatName)

    setChatName('')
}


function createChat() {
    confirmAlert({
        customUI: ({ onClose }) => {
            return (
                <div className='custom-ui'>
                    <h1>Create new chat</h1>
                    <form style={{resize: "vertical"}} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                        <label className="cname-label">Chat Name</label>
                        <input className="cname-input" type='text' placeholder="Type the name of the chat..." onChange={(e) => setChatName(e.target.value)} value={chatName}/>
                        <button className="cancel-button" onClick={onClose}>Cancel</button>
                        <button className="submit-new-chat-button" type='submit'>Create now</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }
    })
}

return (
    <div className="header-left">
        <div className="header-left-column-left">
            <HiMenu className="icon" size={25} style={{ color: "#b3c5d3" }} />
        </div>
        <div className="header-left-column-right">
            <input className="input-search" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar conversa..." />
            <MdAddCircleOutline className="button-new-message" size={25} style={{ color: "#dca297" }} onClick={() => createChat()} />                </div>
    </div>
);

}
```

Comment: Please create an [mcve] in something like codesandbox

Comment: @T J https://codesandbox.io/embed/unruffled-liskov-51971?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

Because once the confirmAlert is created, the submit function will not be changed. So to avoid this, you need to render the chat as a component.

```
function Chat(props){
  var [chatName, setChatName] = useState("");

  const onSubmit = useCallback((e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!chatName) {
      alert("Please write the name of the chat!");
      return;
    }

    alert(chatName);

    setChatName("");
  }, [chatName]);

  return <div className="custom-ui">
    <h1>Create new chat</h1>
    <form style={{ resize: "vertical" }} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <label className="cname-label">Chat Name</label>
      <input
        className="cname-input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Type the name of the chat..."
        onChange={(e) => setChatName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button className="cancel-button" onClick={props.onClose}>
        Cancel
      </button>
      <button className="submit-new-chat-button" type="submit">
        Create now
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
}
function App() {
  function createChat() {
    confirmAlert({
      customUI: ({ onClose }) => {
        return (
          <Chat onClose={onClose}/>
        );
      }
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="header-left">
      <MdAddCircleOutline
        className="button-new-message"
        size={25}
        style={{ color: "#dca297" }}
        onClick={() => createChat()}
      />{" "}
    </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove onSubmit in form element and also remove `type="submit"` on button change it to `onClick={onSubmit}`

```
     <div className="custom-ui">
        <h1>Create new chat</h1>
        <form style={{ resize: "vertical" }} >
          <label className="cname-label">Chat Name</label>
          <input
            className="cname-input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type the name of the chat..."
            onChange={(e) =>
            {
       
            setChatName(e.currentTarget.value)}
            } 
          />
          <button className="cancel-button" onClick={onClose}>
            Cancel
          </button>
          <button className="submit-new-chat-button" onClick={onSubmit}>
            Create now
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
```